# Kinetic JQuery objects - get X/Y of each element in a canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have the brief of setting up a tool that users can add marker points to write notes about imagery.

I have setup a canvas object using the Kinetic library - this is placed over an div containing a dynamic image -  the user can drag markers into position.  When they have finished adding markers I need to scan the canvas and write the x and y positions of each element into an array or multiple variables - which will be used to create a notes PDF server side.

I have got as far as creating the canvas object and the drag functionality works fine - but i dont know how to scan the canvas on completion and loop through each 'latestElement'element to return the x/y values - does anyone have any idea?

My code is below -

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 455,
    height: 500
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var rectX = stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50;
  var rectY = stage.getHeight() / 2 - 25;

  var box = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 5,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable:true
  });

  // add cursor styling

  box.on('dragend', function() {
    var curposX = box.getAbsolutePosition().x;
    var curposY = box.getAbsolutePosition().y;

    alert(curposX  );
    alert(curposY)
  })

  box.on('mouseover', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  });
  box.on('mouseout', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
  });
var curpos = box.getAbsolutePosition().x;
alert(curpos);

  layer.add(box);
  stage.add(layer);

 var countCirc;


function addBox(){
    alert('here')


    var latestElement = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
        y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
        radius: 10,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable:true,


    })
    latestElement.on('dragend', function() {
    var curposX = (this).getAbsolutePosition().x;
    var curposY = (this).getAbsolutePosition().y;

    alert(curposX  );
    alert(curposY)
  })



    layer.add(latestElement);
    latestElement.simulate('mousedown');
    layer.draw();
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Layer.getChildren() to get all objects on that layer.

```
var children = layer.getChildren();
```

That will get you an array of all your circles.

Then iterate through each child circle and  .getX() / .getY() and push to your array

```
Var myPoints=[];
For(var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
    var X=children[i].getX();
    var Y=children[i].getY();
    myPoints.push({ x:X, y:Y });
}
```

Comment: will this order the array elements in the order they were placed on the screen - or the order in which they were scanned - just because i'd need to match each marker with its relevant note..

Comment: They are in the same order as they were added to the layer.  Allow me a memory from my past career as a public accountant and let me describe the order as FIFO--firstIn=firstOut :)